# Excel: Total multiple column values affter returning a value using vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup

I have a table that I enter values into multiple columns.
As each value is entered, that value is used to look up a vertical table that returns a different value. I need to total all these returned values.

So I have entry fields of A1:E1.

If I enter 2 into A1, 2 is then used to lookup the below table returning 2517. If I then enter 4 into B1, 4 is used to lookup the table returning 2034. This value needs to be added to the value returned for 2 i.e.2517 and the value displayed in G1 as shown below.

[image]

I tried using SUM and VLookup in many different ways but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A10:A14=A1:E1)*B10:B14)
```

Comment: @jatsad, please mark the question as answered and click the checkmark to the left of the answer.